# ASP.NET CORE 2.1 WebAPI on IIS versus dotnet.exe Result ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

I had created a WebAPI using Asp.Net Core 2.1, after publishing to folder and execute "dotnet MyApp.dll" the data from sql database were returned correctly BUT IF hosted on IIS, no data were returned WITH error message at console Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

Images below will show the two different result on different processes:

First, Using dotnet.exe at command prompt
[result -> using dotnet.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OOAI.png)

Second, Using IIS
[result -> using IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXqjK.png)

Comment: Could you please show the details error message in the network tag when you access the IIS web api?

Comment: Just fixed the problem...I'm kinda dumb for having incorrect ConnectionString at appsettings.json...

Comment: Thanks anyways @BrandoZhang...

Comment: Post your finding as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so dumb.
I made an adjustment in the connection string...and open the port for inbound and outbound traffic.